# Could there have been wars between the Aztecs and the Persians?

Tags: persia, iran

In the Book of the Kings of [Ferdowsi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdowsi) there is a king named [Zahak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zahhak) or Azhidahak.
I would probably equate it with what we know today as Aztecs.

Some also claim that Atlan (from Atlantis) is another name for Aztec.

Interestingly, in Ferdowsi's book they take control of the Persian land for some time.

The Aztecs also practice human sacrifice, and it was a bloody, fascinating mess. This is also mentioned in the Ferdowsi's book of the kings .

And also in Aztec structures you can clearly see the symbol of snake.

The story of Zahhak originates in the Avesta. But in the tenth century AD, the most famous Iranian poet, Ferdowsi retold this story in his famous book named Shahnameh (Book of Kings). Here is the summary of Ferdowsi’s story:

Zahhak started killing young men and feeding their brains to the evil snakes. Meanwhile, he decided to wage a war against Jamshid, the ruler of the world. Zahhak gathered a huge army and defeated Jamashid in a fierce battle. After killing Jamshid, **Zahhak became the ruler of the world** and took Jamshid’s daughters, Arnavaz and Shahrnavaz as his slaves.

Could there be wars between the Aztecs and the Persians?

Comment: Welcome to the site - I suggest that you check [help] to understand how we do history.  In particular, I suggest that you cite research to establish that there is any relationship between Zahak and Aztec and the claim that "Some claim that Atlan ... "  You may also wish to address the issue of the Atlantic Ocean, and the naval capabilities of each power.  This question may not be history as we understand the term.

Comment: I highly doubt this is even remotely provable, conjectures might be found, and debated but i do not think it's appropriate here

Comment: I believe the Aztecs lacked the technology for ocean crossings. In addition, in the tenth century, they were not yet ruling Tenochtitlán.

Comment: There was a war between the Aztecs and Persians on [June 11, 2006](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_D). Aztecs won 3:1 but were defeated on the 24th by Argentina. Ultimately, the Romans conquered the world that year.

Comment: As far as I understand this question, it is quite roundly rooted in mythology and how it is to be interpreted? Not knowing the rules over there, would this be a possible migration target?

Comment: @LаngLаngС - I'm not a regular there either, but the question itself doesn't seem to be one of what's recorded for mythology, so I doubt it.

Comment: @T.E.D. At present, this is just a strenuous counter-factual. Insert "like" before 'the Aztecs' and I read it as "how do I have to imagine this tale, in real world (non-temporally or historically fact-bound) analogies?" I thought that might work then?

Comment: We generally aren't very lenient with questions that preface extraordinary assertions with no better reference than "some claim".

Answer (score 5):

Not really, no.

In the 10th century CE, the Mesoamerican polity of note was the [Toltecs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toltec_Empire). They were viewed by the later Aztecs sort of in the same way Medieval Europeans viewed the Romans or Greeks, but there's a lot of debate about how much they actually lived up to their later Aztec "press".

[image]

There is no archeological evidence that they ever had the capability of navigating the open ocean, and in fact the lack of any major offshore influence in the nearby Caribbean islands argues strongly against that. Their capital was not on the coast, but rather at [Tula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tula_(Mesoamerican_site)), as far inland as it was possible to get, as was their original homeland. Some trade of the shore-hopping kind was probably a feature of their culture at its height, (note the detached "control" area up in the Yucatan coastal area) but ocean navigation was clearly not what drove it (note also the unusually large amount of coast controlled by neighbors rather than the Toltecs).

Simply, they almost certainly could not navigate out of site of land. In fact no known American civilization had this capability prior to European contact.<sup>*</sup>

So no, nobody from Mesoamerica was sailing eastward over the open ocean to make war upon the old world prior to the modern era.

<sup>* - There is some discussion about whether some of the Andean civilizations might have developed this capability, but a more likely explanation for what evidence we have is that all the open-ocean sailing was being done by Austronesians. Either way, that would be on the South Pacific, not the North Atlantic.</sup>

Comment: I think that Achmed was asking about Persian-Aztec contacts in the time when the story of Zahak and Jamshid was set, not in the time when Ferdowsi wrote the Book of Kings.   Since the historical Median and Achaemenid Persian empires existed 1,500 years before Ferdowsi's era and history doesn't mention Zahak or Jamshid in those eras,  Achmed was asking about an era thousands of years before Ferdowsi, when presumably Mesoamericans had even less ability for ocean navigation.

Comment: @MAGolding - That's a good point, and yeah 500 BC is before both the Aztecs and the Toltecs (although if its like Hebrew stories I've studied better, there's likely some debate as to when exactly the depicted events were supposed to have taken place, and I'm not sure I know enough about that to take a position on it ). This was more like late [Olmec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olmecs#La_Venta), and around the time the Maya were first starting to gather in cities.